# How to disable jquery function for thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two sections of thumbnails one set of thumbnails is without jumbotron container and another set of thumbnails is inside the jumbotron container.

Using hover functionality for without jumbotron container thumbnails and want to remove hover functionality for thumbnails which are inside jumbotron container.

Right now hover functionality which i m using is working on both set of thumbnails.

**How i can disable hover functionality for thumbnails inside Jumbotron container.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.thumbnail').hover(
function( ){
    $(this).find('.caption').fadeOut(slow); //.fadeIn(250)
},
function( ){
$(this).find('.caption').fadeIn(slow); //.fadeOut(205)
}
);
});
```

**Thumbnails without Jumbotron container**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption">
```

**Thumbnails inside jumbotron container**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
   <div class="container">
      <h2>Featured Categories</h2>
         <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
               <div class="thumbnail">
```

How i can disable hover functionality for thumbnails inside jumbotron container.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add an extra class to the ones you want to use. Classes don't necessarily need to be reflective of css styling and can be used for scripting purposes also

```
<div class="thumbnail myHoverClass">
```

JS

```
$('.thumbnail.myHoverClass').hover(...
/* or just */
$('.myHoverClass').hover(...
```

If that's not practical can do

```
$('.thumbnail').not('.jumbotron .thumbnail').hover(...
```

Comment: Something wrong in your execution then. What does `No success` mean? Provide a jsfiddle with sample html

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){

$('.thumbnail').not('.jumbotron .thumbnail').hover(
  function( ){
        $(this).find('.caption').fadeOut(slow); //.fadeIn(250)
    },
    function( ){
    $(this).find('.caption').fadeIn(slow); //.fadeOut(205)
    }
    );
}); this is what i wrote in jquery

Comment: <div class="jumbotron">
       <div class="container">
          <h2>Featured Categories</h2>
             <div class="row"> 
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                   <div class=" jumbotron thumbnail">

Comment: and what happens? Is caption a descendent of thumbnail?

Comment: all thumbnails are getting hovered with fade in and fadeout functionality

Comment: That isn't complete html, create full sample in jsfiddle.net

Comment: it's your css doing it, demo doesn't even include jQuery.js

Comment: still all css, change your hover css and activate jquery , or modify the hover css so it doesn't work on `.jumbotron .thmbnail`

Comment: can you show me how to fix hover css to not work on . jumbotron .thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
if($('.thumbnail').parents().attr('class').indexOf('jumbotron') != -1)
{
//has a parent of jumbotron
}else{
//no parent named jumbotron
}
```

There is a difference in jQuery between `parent()` and `parents()`

Comment: `parents()` returns jQuery object that has no method `indexOf()` , this will just throw an error

Comment: won't work either. `attr()` can only return one value so will be from first element in collection. Would have to use `each` on parents() or `filter()` and that is just way more than is needed. Better to use `!closest(selector).length`